# Vue CRUD using NodeJs (MySql conncetion) - How do I get the data from server-side to client-side?

Tags: mysql, node.js, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to learn more about Vue and to make it interesting I have connected to my MySql-DB using nodeJS.

By following a tutorial (https://webdeasy.de/en/complete-login-system-with-node-js-vue-js-restapi-jwt-part-1-2/) I have a working Login system. Now I want to fetch some data from another table (the table called 'clients') and make a simple CRUD, but I do not understand how to get the data from the Server-side(node-js) to the Client-side(Vue).

I got a connection working where I can output my table data in the console.log - And I know I have use Axios (pointing to localhost:3000 where my server is running) to make it work, but everything I have tried either crashes my app or just doesn't work.

My router.js filer (Server-side) looks like this (I didn't paste all the login 'stuff' to keep clean for you):

```
// routes/router.js

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const uuid = require('uuid');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const db = require('../lib/db.js');
const userMiddleware = require('../middleware/users.js');

// All the login code is here
// All the login code is here
// All the login code is here


db.query
    ("SELECT * FROM clients", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
});


module.exports = router;
```

Which correctly returns this in the console.log:

```
[nodemon] starting `node Server`
The server running on port 3000
[
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Sample Client One',
    email: 'email-one@domain.com',
    phone: '12345678'
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Sample Client two',
    email: 'mail-two@domain.com',
    phone: '12345678'
  }
```

My Clients.vue looks like this now:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Hi {{ username }}, Welcome to Clients</h1>
    <p>{{ secretMessage }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import AuthService from '@/services/AuthService.js';


  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        secretMessage: 'Sample secret message',
        username: '',
      };
    },

    async created() {
      if (!this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
        this.$router.push('/login');
      }
      this.username = this.$store.getters.getUser.username;
      this.secretMessage = await AuthService.getSecretContent();
    },
    methods: {
      logout() {
        this.$store.dispatch('logout');
        this.$router.push('/login');
      }
    }
  };

</script>
```

I have Axios installed, I just removed the import of it to avoid the error. 
As you probably can see a am new at this so let me know if going about this all wrong or if you need to see more of my code.

//Rue

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are fetching the clients from an CRUD endpoint.

For instance, you can add a new `/clients` endpoint where you read all the clients then return them back to client-side with `res.status(200).send(result)`, as follows:

```js
router.get('/clients', (req, res, next) => {
    db.query("SELECT * FROM clients", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(400).send();
          throw err;
        };

        console.log(result);
        res.status(200).send(result);
    });
});
```

And your client-side code now needs to fetch data from server-side. One can create a new file `ClientServices.js` under `services/` folder, like so

```js
// src/services/ClientServices.js

import axios from 'axios';
const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/';
export default {
  getClients() {
    return axios
      .get(url + 'clients/')
      .then(response => response.data);
  }
};
```

The UI code now needs to import the new file and call `getClients` method and list them.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Hi {{ username }}, Welcome to Clients</h1>
    <p>{{ secretMessage }}</p>
  </div>
  <div :key="client.id" v-for="client in clients">
    <strong>client.name</strong>
    <small>client.email</small> | <small>client.phone</small>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import AuthService from '@/services/AuthService.js';
  import ClientService from '@/services/ClientService.js';


  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        secretMessage: 'Sample secret message',
        username: '',
        clients: [],
      };
    },

    async created() {
      if (!this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
        this.$router.push('/login');
      }
      this.username = this.$store.getters.getUser.username;
      this.secretMessage = await AuthService.getSecretContent();

      var self = this
      ClientService.getClients().then((clients) => {
       self.clients = clients;
      });
    },
    methods: {
      logout() {
        this.$store.dispatch('logout');
        this.$router.push('/login');
      }
    }
  };

</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I cant compile now. it looks like its looking for ClientServices.js in the node_modules folder. The error I get is: 

' ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors
12:05:05 PM

This dependency was not found:

* @/services/ClientService.js in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Clients.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

To install it, you can run: npm install --save @/services/ClientService.js'

Comment: Make sure to create the ClientServies.js file in the same directory as AuthService.js

Comment: I found the error - I had called it ClientServices.js (width an s at the end). But I still don't see the output on the client-page. The '<div v-for="client in clients" :key="client.id" >' is not rendered?

Comment: Add a console.log() on ClientService.getClients callback and see if anything gets returned from server side.

Comment: Do you mean in the Clients.vue file right? I'm not sure I'm doing it right, but I'm not getting any log in the console. I tried running 'http://localhost:3000/api/clients' in Postman and got the data, so the connection is working.

Comment: I am not aware of Clients.vue file... But if you use get the data on Postman, then you should also get the clients in the console, when doing:

`ClientService.getClients().then((clients) => {
   // add this new console.log line to view the clients obtained
    console.log('clients', clients)
    self.clients = clients
})
`

Comment: Hmm I still doesn't show up in the console? should I share my code again?